# The Proof of Solutions of $x^n-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

The Hypothesis I want to prove is, the function $f(x)=x^n-1$ has $n$ solutions which lie on the circle group equation of which is $cos(x)+isin(x)$, from $(0,2\pi]$. the solutions of the functions are 
$$e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}*\{{1,2,3,\ldots,n-2,n-1,n}\}}=\Bbb S$$
if when $n$ is an integer and $n\gt0$.

$x=\theta$

The Fundamental theorem of Algebra states with a polynomial of single variable and non-zero of $n^{th}$ degree  there are exactly $n$ complex solutions.

Euler's identity is $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$

lets say $\Bbb S^n-1=0$
$$\Bbb S^n=1$$
I took the natural log on both sides
$$ln(\Bbb S^n)=0$$ $$n*ln(\Bbb S)=0$$
I reverted it back to its original series.
$$n*\left(\frac{2i\pi}{n} * \{{1,2,3,\ldots,n-2,n-1,n}\}\right)=0$$ 
I cancled out the $n$
$$2i\pi*\{{1,2,3,\ldots,n-2,n-1,n}\}=0$$ 
I took both sides to be powers of $e$
$$e^{2i\pi*\{{1,2,3,\ldots,n-2,n-1,n}\}}=1$$ 
$$\{ e^{2i\pi},e^{4i\pi},e^{6i\pi},\ldots,e^{(n-2)2i\pi},e^{(n-1)2i\pi},e^{n2i\pi}\}=1$$

Using Euler's identity $ e^{n2i\pi}=1$ as long n is an integer. Thus proving $\Bbb S$ is the solution of the function $f(x)=x^n-1$

Did I do this proof correct? If not can someone show me how to do it.

Comment: Why not use De Moivre's Formula instead of logarithms? Each one of the numbers in $\mathbb{S}$ is a zero of the polynomial.

Comment: I did not think of that thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\zeta =e^{2\pi i/n}$.
Then $\zeta^j$, for $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, are precisely your claimed zeros.
We can then easily compute that:
$$(\zeta^j)^n-1 = (\zeta^n)^j-1 = (e^{2\pi i})^j-1 = 1-1 = 0$$
And thus we've found $n$ distinct zeros of $x^n-1$.
As we know that:
$$\#\text{ zeros} \leq \deg f(x)$$
We have that we've found all of them (as if there were any more, we'd have $n+k\leq n$ for $k\geq 1$, a contradiction).

Comment: Exactly! ... and there is no need to use the Fundamental theorem of Algebra.